# How to interpret value of categorical crossentropy in Tensorflow / Keras

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

Each batch in `fit` call of my model returns loss value. I use categorical crossentropy loss function.. However I don't understand what the values are.

Half of them are < 1 but there is good number of outliers between 2 and 12..

How one should approach interpreting them in **practical** terms?

*(TF 1.13 python 3.6)*